# How to commit this file to svn?

Tags: iphone, xcode, svn, version-control

I'm on a Mac and would like to commit a file to svn but get an error that the parent folder is lock.

```
Description : Directory '/Developer/Projects/myappproject/trunk/targetfolder/myapp.app/.svn' containing working copy     
admin area is missing
Status : 155005
File : subversion/libsvn_wc/lock.c, 947
```

I run a cleanup from trunk:

```
svn cleanup targetfolder
```

and get this error:

```
svn: 'targetfolder/myapp.app.dSYM' is not a working copy directory
```

The above is a debug symbol file for an iPhone app.  It is really a folder or package.

I can't commit or cleanup.  I do see the above file in CornerStone, which is what I use for source control.  What should I do at this point?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have some corruption there.

I would:

1. Make a copy of the project
2. Checkout a fresh copy of the entire
   project
3. Run a diff on the
   project copy and merge any
   differences to the new project (excluding stuff in .svn directories)
4. Check in the new project.

Comment: You totally lost me.  For step 2, if the project is already checked out, I can't check it out again.  I have no idea on step 3.  What do you mean by "new project"?

Comment: Wade is most likely correct - one of your .svn directories is stuffed.

Comment: It's actually the dSYM and .app files in the targetfolder that are the problem.  I delete those through Finder and can run cleanup successfully.  I can do checkins as well.  I zipped the dSYM folder and was able to check that in.  It doesn't like those two files for some reason.  I can't delete them through svn because I get the "containing working copy admin area is missing" error when trying to commit.  Not sure what to do with them.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by deleting those files, adding back, getting last revision, cleanup until it finally worked.  I don't know the exact steps though.